# In the algebraic formulation of Quantum Mechanics, how do probability amplitudes naturally arise?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, operators, hilbert-space, probability

In the algebraic formulation of quantum mechanics, consider $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ as the set of all bounded operators on $\mathcal{H}$ (with involution, norm, etc.), which form a C*-algebra $C$. States are defined as linear functionals (dual space of $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$), $\phi: C \mapsto \mathbb{C}$.

My question is from the above construction, how does $\phi$ naturally describe a probability amplitude?

Comment: You can't really derive this; you just have to take it as an axiom.

Comment: Whatever formulation you choose of quantum mechanics, $|\phi(x)|^2$ is always *interpreted* as describing the probability density of the state; there is no a priori need for it to be so. Moreover, notice that $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is considered in QFT, not in QM, where almost all operators are actually unbounded (position and momentum, for example).

Comment: So if the notion of probability is _axiomitized_, would that constrict the space of states, $\{\phi \in dual\ of\ \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})\}$ to something smaller?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly define the *probability amplitude* of a pair of pure states which are *normal states* with respect to a given algebraic state and this mathematical object has the same properties as in the standard formulation.

When you have an *algebraic state* on the $C^*$-algebra $A$, that is a *positive* ($\phi(a^*a)\geq 0$), *normalized* ($\phi(I)=1$), linear functional $\phi : A \to \mathbb C$, you can represent it in a Hilbert space by means of the **GNS construction**.

Up to unitary isomorphisms there is a triple $(\cal H, \pi, \Psi)$, where

(i) $\cal H$ is a Hilbert space,

(ii) $\pi: A \to B(\cal H)$ a (continuous) $^*$-representation,

(iii) $\Psi \in \cal H$ a unit vector

such that

(a) $\pi(A)\Psi$ is dense in $\cal H$

and

(b) $\phi(a)= \langle \Psi|\pi(a) \Psi\rangle$.

For the sake of semplicity let us henceforth assume that $\phi$ is pure (i.e. an extreme element of the convex set of algebraic states).

The vectors $\Phi \in \cal H$ represent (up to normalization and a phase) other pure states of the system, the so-called  **normal** pure state of the system in the *folium of $\phi$*

**N.B.** If $\dim(\cal H) = \infty$, there are many other algebraic pure states which cannot be represented as vectors in $\cal H$.

These states are of the form $\pi(a)\Psi$ ($a\neq 0$) or limit of sequences $\pi(a_n)\Psi$ of such vectors due to (a) above. 
Sticking to the most elementary case of a normal pure state defined by the vector  $\pi(a)\Psi$. Algebraically it is defined by the functional
$\phi_a(b) = \frac{\langle \pi(a)\Psi | \pi(b) \pi(a) \Psi\rangle}{\langle \pi(a)\Psi |  \pi(a) \Psi\rangle}$ namely taking advantage of the GNS construction (especially (b) above)
$$A \ni b \mapsto \phi_a(b) = \frac{\omega(a^*ba)}{\omega(a^*a)}\tag{1}\:.$$

The probability amplitude of $\Phi_1 = \phi(a_1)\Psi$ and $\Phi_2 = \phi(a_2)\Psi$ is, as usual,
$$\frac{\langle \Phi_1| \Phi_2 \rangle}{||\Phi_1|| ||\Phi_2||} = \frac{\langle \pi(a_1)\Psi| \pi(a_2)\Psi\rangle}{||\Phi_1|| ||\Phi_2||} = \frac{\langle \Psi| \pi(a_1)^*\pi(a_2)\Psi\rangle}{||\Phi_1|| ||\Phi_2||}= \frac{\langle \Psi| \pi(a_1^*a_2)\Psi\rangle}{||\Phi_1|| ||\Phi_2||}
= \frac{\langle \Psi| \pi(a_1^*a_2)\Psi\rangle}{\sqrt{\phi(a_1^*a_1)\phi(a_2^*a_2)}} = \frac{\phi(a_1^*a_2)}{\sqrt{\phi(a_1^*a_1)\phi(a_2^*a_2)}}\:.$$
We conculide that, given an algebraic pure state $\phi$ and considering two normal pure states $\phi_{a_i}$, $a_1,a_2 \in A$ defined by (1), the **probability amplitude** of $\phi_{a_1}$ and $\phi_{a_2}$ is *defined* as
$$PA(\phi_{a_1},\phi_{a_2}) := \frac{\phi(a_1^*a_2)}{\sqrt{\phi(a_1^*a_1)\phi(a_2^*a_2)}}\:.$$

Comment: Thanks! This is good... just a (sort of tangential) follow up question: Is positivity and normalizability necessary for the GNS construction?

Comment: Normalizability is not necessary, you can perform the construction also for $C^*$-algebras without unit element (see Bratteli-Robinson's textbook). Regarding positivity, the situation is more delicate, however as far as I remember is possible (I suspect that you should use continuous functionals however) see   Hofmann, G.: On GNS representations on inner product spaces.  Communications in Mathematical Physics
191, 299–323 (1998)